# jquery ui resizable triggers onclick event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, onclick, jquery-ui-resizable

I have several divs on a page all with the "appt" class that have onclick events. I am trying to make the same divs resizable using jquery ui.

The problem is that the resize event triggers the onclick event. I have tried the following with no success:

`$(".appt").resizable({.....}).on('resize', function (e) {
         e.stopPropagation(); 
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the element that is being clicked on is the actual element instead of the resizable handle. In the example below it will not execute the onclick functionality when clicking on the resizable handle.

```js
$('.appt').click(function(e) {
  if (e.target === this) {
    console.log('I am being clicked');
  }
});

$('.appt').resizable();
```

```css
.appt {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="appt"></div>
<div class="appt"></div>
<div class="appt"></div>
<div class="appt"></div>
<div class="appt"></div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```